# Validate field by an api call to the web service

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have a form like this:

```
<template>

<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Student__c" onsubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
    <lightning-messages>
    </lightning-messages>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Name" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
    </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="First_name__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
    </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Last_name__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
    </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Email__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
    </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Phone__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
    </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Address__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
    </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="UMCN__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
    </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="TypeOfStudy__c" onchange={handleChange}>
    </lightning-input-field>
                            <template if:true={partTimeCheckbox}>
                                <lightning-input-field field-name="Payer__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
                                </lightning-input-field>
                            </template>
    <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small"
                            variant="brand"
                            name="save"
                            label="Save Student">
    </lightning-button>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

This form to save record:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { createRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import validateUmcn from 
'@salesforce/apex/ValidationService.validateUmcn';
import STUDENT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Student__c';

export default class Poc extends LightningElement {

@track partTimeCheckbox = true;
@track studentRecord = {};

handleFieldChange(e) {
    this.studentRecord[e.currentTarget.fieldName] = e.target.value;

}

handleChange(e) {
    this.studentRecord[e.currentTarget.fieldName] = e.target.value;
    if (this.studentRecord.TypeOfStudy__c == 'Part-Time'){
        this.partTimeCheckbox = true;
      }else{
        this.partTimeCheckbox = false;

    }
}

saveForm() {
    console.log('student for save => ', JSON.stringify(this.studentRecord));
    createRecord({ apiName: STUDENT_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields: this.studentRecord })
        .then(student => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'student created from saveForm => ' + student.id,
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error creating record',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        });
}
async handleFormSubmit(event) {
    // Prevent saving here
    event.preventDefault();
    const fields = event.detail.fields;
    const validationResult = await validateUmcn({ umcn: fields.UMCN__c});
    if(validationResult.success) {
      this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
    } else {
        this.showInfoToast;
            }
  }
  showErrorToast() {
    const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: 'Toast Error',
        message: 'Some unexpected error',
        variant: 'error',
        mode: 'dismissable'
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

}

Now I want to check UMCN__c with an API call. For example I have this: `https://app.test.com/test.php?umcn=UMCN` where `UMCN` at the end is actually the field which will I pass I guess.

And this should be responses.

```
    Response:
- 200 SUCCESS → A successful call to the server can return two different answers
- {"success":true,"message":"OK"}
- {"success":false,"message":"UMCN is invalid. Verification code is not correct."}
- 400 BAD REQUEST → parameter National Identification Number is
empty or it isn’t a number
```

How I can implement this? I'm new to JS, Apex and salesforce so be kind please. :)

`APEX:`

```
    public class ValidationService {
  @AuraEnabled public static Map<String, Object> validateUmcn(String umcn) {
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('callout:umcnValidate?umcn='+umcn);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
    if(res.getStatusCode() == 400) {
      return new Map<String, Object> {
        'success' => false,
        'message' => 'Empty or is not a number'
      };
    }
    return (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
  }
}
```

Comment: No need to ask to be kind, we're not cut from the same cloth as [so]. Welcome to SFSE, and I do hope you enjoy your time here.

Comment: Hi, glad to hear that, anyway, any suggestion how to implement this? :P

Comment: When do you want to validate the UMCN? When the user enters a value, before saving, etc?

Comment: Before saving, so if user insert wrong UMCN number dont save it

Comment: Now, for example if I enter manually on API https://app.test.com/test.php?umcn=123456 it says `{"success":false,"message":"UMCN is invalid. UMCN must be 13 numbers long."}` I just now need to implement this and connect validation with my field from custom object

Answer (score 0):

First, some issues to address. You have a save button where you call `saveForm`. This is going to cause `lightning-record-edit-form` to save the record to the database, and then your button is also saving a copy to the database. Instead, use the `onsubmit` handler of the form directly to deal with this:

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Student__c" onsubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
```

...

```
<lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small"
                  variant="brand"
                  name="save"
                  label="Save Student">
```

Now that we have the correct setup, we just need to handle the submit event.

```
async handleFormSubmit(event) {
  // Prevent saving here
  event.preventDefault();
  const fields = event.detail.fields;
  const validationResult = await validateUmcn({ umcn: fields.UMCN__c });
  if(validationResult.success) {
    this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
  } else {
    // display an error here
  }
}
```

Inside your JavaScript, don't forget to import the method we'll be writing in a minute:

```
import validateUmcn from '@salesforce/apex/ValidationService.validateUmcn';
```

Which will have a class that looks like this:

```
public class ValidationService {
  @AuraEnabled public static Map<String, Object> validateUmcn(String umcn) {
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('callout:umcnValidate?umcn='+umcn);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
    if(res.getStatusCode() == 400) {
      return new Map<String, Object> {
        'success' => false,
        'message' => 'Empty or is not a number'
      };
    }
    return (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
  }
}
```

Note that I used a [Named Credential](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.named_credentials_about.htm&type=5) so you can change the URL at will. You can use a hard-coded endpoint or something else if you like.

Note that you can theoretically call your endpoint directly from JavaScript with [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), but then you'll have to set up CORS in Salesforce, and the other end must also support it. Using Apex avoids a lot of the mess of dealing with security settings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142598/discussion-between-frosty-nah-and-sfdcfox).